# Call generic function from non-generic function in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, generics, interop

`MMCondition` is a protocol defined in Swift, but interoperates with Objective-C (annotated with @objc).

```
@objc public protocol MMCondition {
    static var name: String { get }
    static var isMutuallyExclusive: Bool { get }
}
```

I have the following code:

```
// addCondition cannot be generic as I want it to be accessible from Objective-C as well.
public func addCondition(condition: MMCondition) {
    // How do I initialize OperationConditionImplementer here?
   let operationCondition = OperationConditionImplementer(condition: condition) // doesn't compile
   // Error: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'OperationConditionImplementer<T>' with an argument list of type '(condition: MMCondition)'
   // Can I use condition.dynamicType to init OperationConditionImplementer somehow?
}

struct OperationConditionImplementer<T: MMCondition> {
    let condition: T

    static var name: String {
        return "Silent<\(T.name)>"
    }

    static var isMutuallyExclusive: Bool {
        return T.isMutuallyExclusive
    }

    init(condition: T) {
        self.condition = condition
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Objective-C, you can't use generics as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_78).

> You’ll have access to anything within a class or protocol that’s
>   marked with the @objc attribute as long as it’s compatible with
>   Objective-C. This excludes Swift-only features such as those listed
>   here:
>
> - Generics
>
> ...

So you need to remove completely the generics code. One possible solution might be:

```
@objc protocol MMCondition {
    static var name: String { get }
    static var isMutuallyExclusive: Bool { get }
}

struct OperationConditionImplementer {
    let condition: MMCondition

    var name: String {
        return "Silent<\(condition.dynamicType.name)>"
    }

    var isMutuallyExclusive: Bool {
        return condition.dynamicType.isMutuallyExclusive
    }

    init(condition: MMCondition) {
        self.condition = condition

        // Here decide comparing types
        if condition.dynamicType === ExampleCondition.self {
            print(condition.dynamicType.name)
        }
    }
}
```

So for instance, if you try it out in a playground:

```
class ExampleCondition: NSObject, MMCondition {
    static var name: String  = "ExampleCondition"
    static var isMutuallyExclusive: Bool = false
}

let example = OperationConditionImplementer(condition: ExampleCondition())
```

You'll see "ExampleCondition" printed.

If you eventually switch to pure Swift, you need to specify `T` when initializing a `OperationConditionImplementer`.

You can achieve that defining the `addCondition` method as:

```
func addCondition<T: MMCondition>(condition: T) {
   let a = OperationConditionImplementer<T>(condition: condition)
}
```

Comment: addCondition cannot be generic as I want it to be accessible from Objective-C as well.

Comment: actually you can't use generics in Obj-C, edited answer

Comment: Does this mean func addCondition (without the generics) in my example cannot instantiate OperationConditionImplementer correctly?

Comment: Correct, you need the type to instantiate the implementer, and that cannot be decided at runtime. One option would be, as you suggested, to build it up using an initializer and checking the type in there, but you'll need to remove completely all the generics stuff in order to use it from Obj-C

Comment: Since isMutuallyExclusive and name are static, that approach presents a different set of problems.

Comment: What problems? You can call condition.dynamicType.name, can't you?

Comment: condition won't be accessible within OperationConditionImplementer's implementation of static var name: String { get } since condition is not static. No?

Comment: If you build up a constructor in OperationConditionImplementer with a condition as param then you should be able to call condition.dynamicType.name on that condition. Yes, condition remains non-static, and with that way you can access its static/class iVars & methods.

Comment: updated answer, so you can check the checking dynamicType at the initializer approach

Comment: I see so name and isMutuallyExclusive on OperationConditionImplementer don't need to static since it doesn't implement MMCondition. I don't know what I was thinking but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Correct, as those properties rely on condition, a non-static variable.

Answer (score 2):

Since Swift 2.0 instances of generic **classes** can implement Objective-C protocols. What won't be possible I believe is having a struct implement the protocol. In fact I expect that your protocol may need to inherit from NSObjectProtocol to be usable in Objective-C which would then prevent you from implementing the protocol with structs or enums.

You also rightly mention that you can't access generic functions from Objective-C.

For a concrete example of using a generic to fulfil an Objective-C protocol have a look at [this blog post](http://blog.human-friendly.com/swift-2-xcode-7-gm-at-least-generic-support-for-at-objc-protocols).